# UVA Online Judge Runtime Error on 706 LCD Display

Tags: c++, visual-c++, runtime-error

I am new to C++ programming and trying to solve some problems on UVa Online Judge our prof gave us.
Right now I am on the 706 LCD Display (https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=16&page=show_problem&problem=647).
In my IDE (VS2015 Community) everything works fine and as expected but when I'm trying to submit my code I get a runtime error. Unfortunately they don't show more details about it.
I tried to run my code in several online c++ compilers (such as http://cpp.sh/) and never expirienced an error.

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

// set the "borders" for each number
#define ZERO 1+2+4+16+32+64;
#define ONE 4+32;
#define TWO 1+4+8+16+64
#define THREE 1+4+8+32+64
#define FOR 2+4+8+32
#define FIVE 1+2+8+32+64
#define SIX 1+2+8+16+32+64
#define SEVEN 1+4+32
#define EIGHT 1+2+4+8+16+32+64
#define NINE 1+2+4+8+32+64

using namespace std;

// draw the digits line by line. some lines (first, middle, last) only represents horizontal lines, where all other lines represent vertical lines
// in every line for every digit is checked wheter the lines on the current position must be drawn or not.
void drawDigits(int* digits, int cDigits, int height, int width) {
    int middle = (height >> 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cDigits; ++j) {

            if (i == 0) {
                if (digits[j] & 1) {
                    cout << " ";
                    for (int y = 0; y < width - 2; ++y) cout << "-";
                    cout << " ";
                }
                else {
                    for (int y = 0; y < width; ++y) cout << " ";
                }
            }
            else if (i < middle) {
                if (digits[j] & 2) {
                    cout << "|";
                    for (int y = 0; y < width - 2; ++y) cout << " ";
                }
                else {
                    for (int y = 0; y < width - 1; ++y) cout << " ";
                }
                if (digits[j] & 4) {
                    cout << "|";
                }
                else {
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            else if (i == middle) {
                if (digits[j] & 8) {
                    cout << " ";
                    for (int y = 0; y < width - 2; ++y) cout << "-";
                    cout << " ";
                }
                else {
                    for (int y = 0; y < width; ++y) cout << " ";
                }
            }
            else if (i < height - 1) {
                if (digits[j] & 16) {
                    cout << "|";
                    for (int y = 0; y < width - 2; ++y) cout << " ";
                }
                else {
                    for (int y = 0; y < width - 1; ++y) cout << " ";
                }
                if (digits[j] & 32) {
                    cout << "|";
                }
                else {
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            else {
                if (digits[j] & 64) {
                    cout << " ";
                    for (int y = 0; y < width - 2; ++y) cout << "-";
                    cout << " ";
                }
                else {
                    for (int y = 0; y < width; ++y) cout << " ";
                }
            }

            if (j != cDigits - 1) cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        if (i == height - 1) cout << endl;
    }
}

// a given number (c-string) is prepared for drawing
// find out the length of the 'number' and assign for each digit the defined value in the ditigs-array
void drawLCD(int size, char* number) {
    if (size < 1 || size > 10) return;
    int length = 0;
    while (*(number + length) != '\0') {
        ++length;
    }

    int* digits = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int t = 0;
        switch (*(number++) - '0') {
        case 0:
            t = ZERO;
            break;
        case 1:
            t = ONE;
            break;
        case 2:
            t = TWO;
            break;
        case 3:
            t = THREE;
            break;
        case 4:
            t = FOR;
            break;
        case 5:
            t = FIVE;
            break;
        case 6:
            t = SIX;
            break;
        case 7:
            t = SEVEN;
            break;
        case 8:
            t = EIGHT;
            break;
        case 9:
            t = NINE;
            break;
        default:
            t = ZERO;
        }
        digits[i] = t;
    }

    drawDigits(digits, length, 2 * size + 3, size + 2);
}

void callDraws(int cNums, int* size, char** numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cNums; ++i) {
        drawLCD(size[i], numbers[i]);
    }
}

// gets the integer value from a number in a c-string
int getInt(char* str) {
    int length = 0;
    int res = 0;
    while (*(str + length) != '\0') {
        ++length;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        res += (int)pow(10, length - (i + 1)) * (*(str++)-'0');
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    char* n = new char[10];
    int counter = 0;
    int* size = new int[1000];
    char** numbers = new char*[1000];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        size[i] = 0;
        numbers[i] = "";
    }

    while (cin >> n) {
        if (size[counter] <= 0) {
            int nn = getInt(n);
            if (nn <= 0) break;
            size[counter] = nn;
        }
        else {
            numbers[counter++] = n;
            n = new char[10];
        }
    }

    callDraws(counter, size, numbers);

    return 0;
}
```

When I enter a 'return 0' before the call to callDraws() the code terminates. So the error must be somewhere in printing the digits.

Where is this runtime error or how can I find it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you pass characters by value rather than pointer.  Pointers can lead to troubles.

Comment: You can replace your `getDigits` function with `digit = character - '0';`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the `getDigits`.
But I don't understand where I should pass the character by value instead pointer. I pass characters by pointers to the methods `getInt`, `callDraws` and `drawLCD`. In all of them I use them as string, so I _have to_ pass the pointers. Or am I wrong with that?

Comment: There are lots of **uninitialized variables** here. Those things are considered by C++ specs as undefined behavior. You might want to initialize your variables first before proceeding into evaluation of their values.

Comment: @mr5 where are those 'lots of' uninitialized variables? I already replaced the `getDigits` method as @Thomas-Matthews said and then there's only the `int t;` in `drawLCD`. Or am I missing something here?
btw: I replaced it with `int t = -1;` but it still doesn't work =/

Comment: @MichaelRoth I will give you a hint. After this line `int* size = new int[1000]` try printing all its values. I would guess that the output are not what you are expecting.

Comment: Ok, that really wasn't what I'd expected... I inserted a for-loop to set all values in `size` to 0 and all values in `numbers` to `""`. Unfortunately it still generates a runtime error.
I updated the code in the post to the state it is right now.